# Sell Monero like in iqOptions

Tags: mining

I have bought a Monero mining contract and Monero’s price is going down, I thought about betting that the price will go down to limit losses like in iqOptions with Monero, the options from other sites just sells the money.
What sites lets you bet that the price will go down ?